# Problems with wireless connection (Win8.1 laptop)

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, 64-bit

I'm having 3 weird issues with connecting to a wireless connection on my laptop running Windows 8.1.

1) The icon shows the wired connection icon (monitor with a cord) and not the wireless (bars) icon, even though my wired adapter is completely disabled and wifi is set to highest priority in adapter settings

2) The computer refuses to remember the network, and every time I restart/resume from hibernate/sleep, I gotta manually reconnect to wifi again, as well as enter password (can't remember password either). I have checked the "automatically connect" box

3) After connecting to the network, it would always say "connection is limited", even though I have 0 problems with the internet (not slow, won't d/c, etc), not even the icon has a ! or X on it. Running network troubleshooter returns "cannot identify the problem" within 5 seconds, and there are no devices in device manager (that's related to network) with a !

Does anyone know how to fix these issues? I've already googled but didn't find any solutions that worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet but I will update the answer if it solves your problem.

[Try rolling back or updating the drivers](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dennis_schnell/archive/2013/08/31/windows-8-1-wifi-showing-quot-limitied-quot-or-quot-no-internet-access-quot.aspx). Sometimes the driver automatically installed by Windows 8.1 causes problems.

Roll back:

1. Open Device Manager in Control Panel.
2. Find your device under Network adapters and double click.
3. Go to the Driver tab.
4. Select Roll Back Driver.

Update:

1. Open Device Manager in Control Panel.
2. Find your device under Network adapters and double click.
3. Go to the Driver tab.
4. Select Update Driver...
5. Select Browse my computer for driver software.
6. Select Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer.
7. Select the latest one from the list and click Next.
8. If it does not work, choose a later one.